# Change Title Type

Tags: hooks, title

I'd like to change the title field of a post in admin panel. I'd like this field was "textarea" instead of being "input type='text'".

Would it be possible through any hook in functions.php?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a default field or a custom field?

Comment: It's a default field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as this is a default field, i don't think it is possible to achieve what you want with the help function hooks,
however you can do this by editing edit-form-advanced.php file inside wp-admin folder,

the code you may want to edit is located in line # 291,

this is the input type for title field

```
    <input type="text" name="post_title" size="30" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo esc_attr( htmlspecialchars( $post->post_title ) ); ?>" id="title" autocomplete="off" />
```

Do this at your own risk as you are going to edit wordpress core file, once you edit this you might not able to update your wordpress automatically

Comment: I have already thought of this option, but I didn't want to modify original code. Anyway, thank you very much.